# iPhone's UILabel with URL detection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, controls, uilabel

I'm looking for an iPhone control that can simply display some text and detect 
URL's (http, email, tel) inside that text. UILabel doesn't support URL 
detection. UITextView can do that, but it's too heavy for use in chat 
application that I'm developing. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same tools that the facebook app uses: three20

Joe Hewitt, the developer behind the facebook app has open sourced much of his work.  You can get it and many other goodies [here](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20).

Answer (score 0):

Craig Hockenberry did it for Twitteriffic.  He provides the downloads here:
http://furbo.org/2008/10/07/fancy-uilabels/