# UIWebView url problem

Tags: url, ios4, uiwebview, uitextview, detection

I've got a viewController with an TextView where feed are loaded in and when there's a link in it and you tab on it a webview should load up with the link.
So I've created a webview, but how should the if statement that says: "if there's a url load the webviewcontroller with this url" look?

In the WebViewController I've got:

`[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]]];`

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Are you asking how to parse the text in your rss feeds and detect the URLs?

Comment: What you have is correct if you're just loading a URL. If the URL is the text of your textView, then:

[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[myTextView text]]]];

Is that what you're asking?

Comment: i want to detect the url from the textview. the text view is for example: blablabala http://www.google.de bla bla. Now I want to detect the url and give it to the webviewcontroller where the webview should load this url

Answer (score 0):

Here are some resources that should get you going:

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/129873-detect-url-in-nstextview.html (this is for Mac OS, but might be helpful nonetheless)

For iPhone: [iPhone's UILabel with URL detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544604/iphones-uilabel-with-url-detection)

And: [How to make UITextView detect links for website, mail and phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995219/how-to-make-uitextview-detect-links-for-website-mail-and-phone-number)

Enjoy!